# EF Migrations without DbContext connection string

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to create migrations using the standard EF Core CLI without specifying a connection string on the DbContext?

Reason, my team would like to use Azure Pipelines to automate migration creation, but we have it in a separate project from the app that is consuming it (in it's own class library). As it is right now, we have a separate startup project (.NET Core 3.1 ConsoleApp) which has the DbContext DI registrations and sets the DbContextOptions. But I was curious if there was a way to wire that up without specifying a connection string and instead giving it a database provider of some sorts so its has enough to go by.

Current implementation:

```
var connectionString = "Server=blah;Database=blah, etc...";

services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(connectionString, ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)));
```

Desired implementation:

```
services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseMySql(someDatabaseProviderInfoObjectThatDoesNotNeedConnectionStringToWork);
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Hi Jason. I've also faced the exact same flow and did not find any solution. Were you able to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sqlite for development.

```
services.AddDbContext<SomeDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlite("DataSource=mydatabase.db");
```